# Dynamic coldfusion cfif statement

Tags: coldfusion

I have a statement like this:

```
<cfif string contains "this" or string contains "that" or etc.>
```

The contains comes from a database that might be two or more things to search for in the if statement. How can I write the cfif to keep adding OR until all of the things to search for are in the if statement above?

Comment: Voting to close as the question doesn't display even a minimum amount of research into the topic, nor identifies what has already been tries. It sounds like a "do my work for me" sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to achieve your goal.  One is to use list functions.

```
<cfif ListFind(ValueList(YourQuery.YourField), YourString) gt 0>
```

That would be appropriate if you want your string to be one of the values.  Or you could do something like this, which would match the logic from your question.

```
</cfscript>
 MyString = "DISCHARGE";
SearchResult = false;
</cfscript>

<cfquery name="x" datasource="dw">
select trim(event_name) event_name
from event
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="x">
<cfif MyString contains event_name >
<cfset SearchResult = true>
<cfbreak>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#SearchResult#">
```

And then there is the ever popular query of queries.

```
<cfquery name="q2" dbtype="query">
select count(*) matches
from YourFirstQuery
where TheField like <cfqueryparam value="%#string#%">
</cfquery>
```

These all have slightly different logic, so you have to know what you want to do before you try to code it.

Comment: For case insensitive searches, there is `ListFindNoCase()`